# Find and Replace Text on Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I have a Google form with several sections. I’m trying to find and replace certain words or strings of text throughout the form (for example, replace “Central High School” with “North Middle School”). The built-in CTRL+F function has only Find, not Replace. Is there a way to build a script that would find and replace?  I currently have about 44 instances to replace.

I searched for an answer but current answers only seem to address other G-Suite tools like Docs, Sheets, and Slides, not Forms.